# Meaning of `<meta charset="B">` in an HTML document

Tags: html, encoding

I am learning HTML now, and one aspect related to the encoding confuses me.

Imagine, I open my test editor, write some HTML code and save it using charset *A* (e.g. UTF-8 or ANSI or something else). Then in my view the following happens:

1. all characters I have typed are mapped to certain numbers, the mapping is specified by the charset *A*;
2. the numbers are saved in the computer memory in their binary representation as sequences of *0* s and *1* s.

In the HTML document I have just saved there is a line `<meta charset="B">` where *B* is another charset different from *A*.

What now happens when I attempt to open the HTML document with a browser? Will it map according to charset *B* the sequences of *0* s and *1* s  which comprise my document to wrong characters (not the ones I meant when I wrote the document) and thus will display some rubbish?

As you see with this question I am trying to understand the real meaning of `<meta charset="B">` in an HTML document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, exactly, you have understood correctly. This is precisely how [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) is being born; something is trying to interpret a binary sequence using the wrong character set, which either leads to unintended/wrong characters being displayed, or the document failing to decode entire, at which point the concrete behaviour depends on the application trying to do the decoding.

The `<meta charset>` element (and really primarily the `Content-Type` HTTP header) are advisory, informing the client (browser) in what character set it should interpret the document. Otherwise the client cannot know. If the server/document are advising the wrong charset, the result will be broken to some degree or another.

Comment: Let me ask then a follow up question. A browser to start decoding my HTML would firstly need to decode the line `<meta charset="B">`, but it can not do it, because it does not know what charset to use, because it has not read the line `<meta charset="B">` yet.

Comment: Ah, catch 22. Indeed, that's why the `Content-Type` HTTP header overrides the `<meta>` element and should be the primarily preferred way to specify the document's encoding. In cases where it's missing, browsers employ various techniques; in a nutshell it goes something like 1) inspect a few bytes to try to guess the encoding, 2) decode the first kilobyte or so and see if you can find a `<meta>` charset declaration, 3) restart with a better informed guess. That's why the `<meta>` element should be one of the first things in the document.